# What's the "Super feature"?

Tags: thief

I just bought Thief for PS4 and installed the first update.

Curious about what the first update includes, this is what I saw<sup>**1**</sup>:

> Following features are added:
>   - Super feature
>   - Bug fixes
>   - Make sure to visit https://ps4.scedev.net/docs/ps4-en,Content_Information-Specifications-orbis,Update_Information/1

The link is dead, but I'm more interested in this so-called "*super feature*"; what is it?

All I can find online is a mention of [an update for the PC version](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=141833), and [a 6 GB update for the Xbox One](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691088-xbox-one/68661874)<sup>**2**</sup>.

---

<sup>**1**</sup>: Press the <kbd>OPTIONS</kbd> button and select "*Update History*" to view a game's update history.
<sup>**2**</sup>: Pretty sure I didn't download such a huge patch on my PS4; not when it only took 3 seconds.